# How to upload folder by using react-dropzone-uploader pacakge?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

How to upload folder by using `react-dropzone-uploader` package?
I'm using below code but it does not working.

```js
<Dropzone
  getUploadParams={FilesMeta}
  getFilesFromEvent={getFilesFromEvent}
  PreviewComponent={Preview}
  selectFileInput={selectFileInput}
  directory=""
  webkitdirectory=""
  type="file"
  multiple={true}
  inputContent={
    <div>
      <p className="dropText">Drag and Drop or Browse Files</p>
    </div>
  }
/>
```

I'm expecting folder upload on drag and drop along with all the files inside that folder.